# I have written code for chat application, works fine for iOS 12 but in iOS 13, it return nil value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

[image]I have written code for chat application,works fine for iOS 12 ,and in iOS 13, it return nil value.

this is my code snippet for dateformatter.

```
-(NSDate *)stringToDateNew:(NSString*)strDate withForamt:(NSString *)strFormat {
   @try
   {
       NSDate *myDate;

       if(strDate!=NULL)
       {
           NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
           [dateFormat setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strFormat]];
           NSLocale * enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] ;
           if (enUSPOSIXLocale == nil) {
               enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
           }
           else
           {
            [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
            [dateFormat setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
            myDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:strDate];
            return myDate;
           }

       }
       return NULL;

   }
   @catch (NSException *exception)
   {
       NSLog(@"Excption in AppDelegate : stringToDate %@:%@",exception.name,exception.reason);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and point out the exact line causing the problem. Also include specific details about the values being passed into the method.

Comment: now check @rmaddy

Comment: That shows the format but what is the value passed to the `strDate` parameter?

Comment: passed date in the format " 20 October 2019",@rmaddy

Comment: Do you think that the string `20 October 2019` is matched by your format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzz` ? You need to pass a format that actually matches the date string you are trying to parse.

Comment: but why it works for os 12,and not for 13.@rmaddy

Comment: That format with that date string will not work under any version of iOS.

Comment: it returns nil value in os 13,but it is perfect in till os 12,@rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the withformat "yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS".It Will work for os 13 as well.